# is it possible to read an Excel through powershell like this?

Tags: excel, powershell

I have this excel

[image]

every row is an automation script I need to execute with certain parameters, the excel is because every script receives different parameters, and I need to do a powershell script that reads the excel file and for each row, execute that process id(script) and send those parameters

is there a way to do that? is it doable?

so far I have this

```
$file = "C:\Users\MX02689\Documents\Parametros.xlsx"
$sheetName = "Sheet1"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$objExcel.Visible=$false
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count

$colMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Columns).count

$rowName,$colName = 1,1
#the idea here is that for each row that has values do this
for($i=1;$i-le $colMax-1; $i++)

#The idea here is that if (parameter 1 -eq 1 ){
execute the command we use to send the scripts process id; "parameter2 parameter 3 parameter 4" 
}else{
skip the row and go to the next one
}
{
Write-Output("" + $sheet.Cells.Item($rowName,$colName+$i).text)

}
```

am I in the right direction? thank you for the help :)

am I in the right direction?  is it doable what Im trying to do? is there a optimized way to achieve this? thank you for your help :)
Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Excel is not the fastest or easiest way of doing this with PowerShell.
It can be done like this:

```
$file = "D:\Parametros.xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
$colMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Columns).count

for ($row = 2; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {   # skip the header row
    $params = @()
    for ($col = 1; $col -le $colMax; $col++) {
        $params += $sheet.Cells.Item($row, $col).Value()
    }
    # execute the command. For demo, just show the parameters used
    'Invoke-Command parameters: {0}' -f ($params -join ', ')
}

$objExcel.Quit()
# clean-up used Com objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)    | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Far more convenient would be to save your Excel file as CSV and use that:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Parametros.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # execute the command. For demo, just show the parameters used
    'Invoke-Command parameters: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}' -f $_.'process id', $_.parameter1, $_.parameter2, $_.parameter3, $_.parameter4
}
```

Demo output for both methods:

> ```
> Invoke-Command parameters: 235522, 1, testinguser3, Mko12345, something
> Invoke-Command parameters: 235266, 0, testinguser4, Mko12346, something
> Invoke-Command parameters: 235266, 1, testinguser5, Mko12347, something
> ```

---

From your comment, I now understand what the "1" or "0" means in parameter1.
Below find the adjusted codes for Excel aswell as the CSV method:

Method for Excel:

```
$file = "D:\Parametros.xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
$colMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Columns).count

for ($row = 2; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {   # skip the header row
    $params = @()
    for ($col = 1; $col -le $colMax; $col++) {
        $params += $sheet.Cells.Item($row, $col).Value()
    }
    # if the second parameter value converted to int = 1, proceed; if 0 skip the line
    if ([int]$param[1] -ne 0) {
        # execute the command. For demo, just show the parameters used
        'Invoke-Command parameters: {0}' -f ($params -join ', ').TrimEnd(", ")
    }
}

$objExcel.Quit()
# clean-up used Com objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)    | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Method for CSV file:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Parametros.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # get the field values from the row in array $params (not a fixed number of fields)
    $params = @($_.PsObject.Properties).Value

    # if the second parameter value converted to int = 1, proceed; if 0 skip the line
    if ([int]$params[1] -ne 0) {
        # execute the command. For demo, just show the parameters used
        'Invoke-Command parameters: {0}' -f ($params -join ', ').TrimEnd(", ")
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! the csv file example you gave, I believe I can't use it because there may be more than 3 parameters or less than 3, the 1,0 cell it will be the flag to indicate if the script should read the row or just go to the next one

Comment: something like this, 
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Parametros.csv' | ForEach-Object { 
if(1st cell -eq 1){
read row and send the parameters needed, either there are 4 or 10 
}else{
skip to the next row
}
}

Comment: @HeberSolis Aha, now I see what the "1" or "0" should do. I have added new code to tackle that. Also I added code to handle this in CSV file, where the number of parameters is not fixed anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! thank you so so much just one thing, I don't know if it's possible but works flawlessly, the output show this 
Invoke-Command parameters: 235522, 1, testinguser3, Mko12345, , , 
Invoke-Command parameters: 235266, 1, testinguser5, Mko12347, , , 
it would be possible to just show this?
Invoke-Command parameters: 235522, 1, testinguser3, Mko12345
Invoke-Command parameters: 235266, 1, testinguser5, Mko12347

without the commas at the end

Comment: @HeberSolis Easy fix, just append `.TrimEnd(", ")`. Already done this in the code.

Comment: thank you so so much!! :D :D I just need to not show the 1 because that's just a flag haha but I search that on my own, you have helped me so much! thank you so much!! once again :D